# running time of referencing an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a javascript `array1` containing 10 000 items

what is the running time of:

```
 var array2=new array();
 array2.push(array1);
```

and what is the running time of

```
var object={};
object['array2']=array1;
```

are both O(n) ? thanks for explanation.

Comment: Might be more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com, where you're likely to get a more detailed, probably more scientific answer.

Comment: You should build your own test cases in [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/).  That's the only way to answer questions like this and then test it in the browsers you care about.

Comment: here's some interesting reading for you http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/10/javascript-array-performance/

Comment: @Michael: No. This is a specific question about a programming language. Much, much, much better than all the "fix my code for me plz" crap milling about; _this_ is precisely the sort of question that _should_ be on SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They *should* both be amortized O(1) operations.

This (obviously) depends on the browser's JS implementation, but any sane one should use an arraylist-like implentation for `[]`s, and a hashtable-like `{}`. Arraylists and hashtables both have amortized O(1) `insert` runtime.

Comment: is there arraylist and hashtable in javascript?

Comment: `[]` is more-or-less an arraylist, and `{}` is more-or-less a hashtable.